# Message Header Size for JMS producer in ActiveMq v5.10

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I was trying to use Message Size related stats
(Minimum message size, Maximum message size, Average message size, Total message size by using

> [DestinationStatistics](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.10.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/DestinationStatistics.html).getMessages().getCount()

) provided in ActiveMQ v5.10 and found that header size is 1028 bytes (send message of different sizes and size returned by API is 1028 bytes more). I am not able to understand why size is this.

Is it prefixed? Is there anyway to see what constitute header.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
So basically producer is sending a text message of 1024 bytes (chars) using java code on a queue to broker which is received by consumer listening onto that queue. I am logging message sizes using the above said API and I found that message size reported is 2052 bytes and not 1024 bytes.

Comment: What header size stats?  What did you do in your code?  What was the expectation?  Question is to vague to provide any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the trace-level logging for ActiveMQ in your client application to see more details about sent messages. The messages can and will contain lots of "metadata" the brokers and clients use, for example sending a simple test-message within our own server software shows the following:

> [scheduler-1] TRACE org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession  -
>   ID:esaj-HP-59250-1410162276798-1:1:36 sending message:
>   ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false,
>   messageId = ID:esaj-HP-59250-1410162276798-1:1:36:1:2,
>   originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId =
>   ID:esaj-HP-59250-1410162276798-1:1:36:1, destination =
>   topic://server.diagnostics, transactionId = null, expiration =
>   1410162336586, timestamp = 1410162324586, arrival = 0, brokerInTime =
>   0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent
>   = false, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content =
>   null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null,
>   redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {`** OMITTED, OUR CUSTOM PROPS **`}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable
>   = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = { `** THE ACTUAL DATA **` }}

This was with ActiveMQ 5.9, but as you can see, there's lots of header data that ActiveMQ produces on its own. As for how to actually get rid of it, I'm not sure, I'm not really an ActiveMQ-specialist, but I'd say a kilobyte of header data seems just "normal" for ActiveMQ.

**Edit**: I took a look into our message brokers, and all queues and topics show average message sizes above 1024 bytes, which lead me to delve a bit into the ActiveMQ (5.9) source. I found this in *org.apache.activemq.command.Message*:

```
/**
 * The default minimum amount of memory a message is assumed to use
 */
public static final int DEFAULT_MINIMUM_MESSAGE_SIZE = 1024;

//Omitted other stuff...

@Override
public int getSize() {
    int minimumMessageSize = getMinimumMessageSize();
    if (size < minimumMessageSize || size == 0) {
        size = minimumMessageSize;
        if (marshalledProperties != null) {
            size += marshalledProperties.getLength();
        }
        if (content != null) {
            size += content.getLength();
        }
    }
    return size;
}

protected int getMinimumMessageSize() {
    int result = DEFAULT_MINIMUM_MESSAGE_SIZE;
    //let destination override
    MessageDestination dest = regionDestination;
    if (dest != null) {
        result=dest.getMinimumMessageSize();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And getSize() is used in many places, like *MessageQueue*, *ActiveMQSession* etc. I didn't delve much deeper, but it looks like at least 1024 bytes (1 kilobyte) is either reserved or at least assumed in statistics for each message. The statistics seem to be gathered in *Queue*- and *Topic*-classes, and uses the value returned by `getSize()`, here's for example the beginning of Queue.messageSent:

```
final void messageSent(final ConnectionContext context, final Message msg) throws Exception {
    destinationStatistics.getEnqueues().increment();
    destinationStatistics.getMessages().increment();
    destinationStatistics.getMessageSize().addSize(msg.getSize());
```

I don't know whether 1024 bytes is actually transmitted over the wire when sending an empty message, but at least the statistics seem to assume so.

Comment: can you please check whether you are getting same header size?

Comment: @learner I'm not at work anymore for today, and don't have ActiveMQ -setup at home, but I'll try to check tomorrow if I have the time.

Comment: This is really helpful, this do explain somewhat but still if the message itself is 1024 bytes then what about header size..., as when I send a text message and retrieved text from it, it is still the size I have sent...

Answer (score 2):

The size you are seeing is an approximation of total message size.  The broker will not track exact messages sizes as parts of the message are unmarshaled on the Broker prior to being dispatched into the core where these statistics are updated.  The additional byte overhead value of 1024 is added to account for bytes added when the message is encoded and sent on the wire.  There is no way to separate from those statistics what the size of the message properties was vs the size of the body etc, this number is just a best guess at total encoded message size.

Comment: So there is no explanation of these additional 1028 bytes ?

Comment: If you need to know, the source code is freely available for you to examine.

Comment: Can I print message which are with broker (message + header) ?

Comment: You can browse a Queue and write code to print things that you want to see.

Comment: by browsing and getting a message am just able to get byte sequence only

Comment: Which should be a good indication that what you are trying to do doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: But doesn't 1028 bytes look like  big overhead if I am sending message ~100 bytes ?